# Changes to dataset of an existing ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services

First of all i'm new to ssrs. I have to make changes to an existing ssrs report. I have made changes to the stored procedure which this report calls and it works fine after execution. now i have to add a value to a drop down on the UI part. I opened the .rdl file to add the value to the existing data-set. But when i open the .rdl file in visual studio i only see xml. when i open in report builder i see the data-set to which i should add this new value but it directs towards an xml link. Not sure where these xml files are and how to proceed further. any help please.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't set up Visual Studio to edit SSRS reports. You need to use the Visual Studio installer to install the Sql Server Data Tools and then install the Microsoft Reporting Services Projects extension.

Answer (score 0):

You need Visual studio with extension from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017) and from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55252)

Once you have your Visual studio set up you can edit your Report very easily with UI. UI looks something like below

[image]

If you see below image I have few parameters as

[image]

I can extend parameters value as

[image]